# screen inside screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

In my terminal I run a screen. Obviously I have several tabs and in one of them I connect to a remote server. In this one I have a detached running screen, I attach it but I can't switch its tabs.

PS: the remote running screen has been here since many months ago and is never killed. However the local one is killed every night (company policy)

Comment: @StephenKitt This is indeed the solution to my problem, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a different command character for the inner screen, for instance by starting it with:

```
screen -e'^Bb'
```

So that `^B` be the command character instead of `^A` and a literal `^B` be entered `^Bb`.

Or you'll need to enter `^Aa` (assuming the outer `screen` was started with the default settings, that is as if with `screen -e'^Aa'`) for the outer screen to pass that `^A` to the inner screen.

That also means that to enter a literal `^A` in the inner `screen`, you'd need to enter `^Aa^Aa`.

From within `screen`, you can change the default command character with the `escape` command. So for your inner screen already started in an outer screen both using `^A` as their command character, you'd enter `^Aa:escape ^Bb` to change the command character to `^B`

Comment: works as well, great!! thx!